# weird way to calculate limits

Tags: limits

i was asked to discover the limit such as this way and i wantto know if i did it alright or i miss something

been $a_n$ an succesion

$$a_1=10;a_n=6-\frac{5}{a_{n-1}}$$
it looks like the succession always decree

$$a_2=6-\frac{5}{6};a_3=6-\frac{10}{11};a_4=6-\frac{55}{56}$$
and it does cause, for induction u can know
$$0<\frac{5}{a_k}<1  \forall k>1$$
then
$$5<6-\frac{5}{a_k}<6$$
i suposse than limit exist and y call him L so
L=$lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_{n+1}6-\frac{5}{a_n}=6-\frac{5}{lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n}=6-\frac{5}{L}$
so
$$L=6-\frac{5}{L}$$
what implies
$0=L^2-6L+5$
for baskara i know
$L=5$ or $ L=1$
but i know it cant be 1 cause every $a_n$ its $5<a_n<6$
so then L must be 5

Comment: This is justified by the monotone sequence theorem.

Comment: so u say its aprovate for u?

Answer (score 1):

We have $$a_n-5={a_{n-1}-5\over a_{n-1}}\quad (*)$$ As $a_1>5$ we get $a_n>5$ for any $n,$ by $(*)$ and the induction argument. Therefore $$0<a_n-5\le {1\over 5}(a_{n-1}-5)$$ By iterating we get $$0<a_n-5\le {1\over 5^{n-1}}(a_1-5)={1\over 5^n}$$ Hence $a_n$ tends to $5$ at exponential rate.